# Math.random() only two numbers

Tags: math, random, numbers

i want to create with `Math.random()` only the numbers 2 and 4. 
How can i do that?

Thanks for your support

Comment: You don't specify the language. Is this Java? JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int twoOrFour = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 2 : 4;`

Comment: It's the so called ternary operator. It's the same, as if writing: int a=Math.random();if(a<0.5)twoOrFour=2;else 4;

Comment: Look here for this operator: http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018

Comment: Thanks! You rock dude!

Answer (score 0):

'?' And ':' are know as ternary operators. They are a replacement for if - else.  The previous code should look this way with if-else

`if (Math.random ()<0.5)twoOrFour=2;
else twoOrFour=4;`